# DatePicker Vuetify error when set null as default value

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have form that need datepicker but not required, and I want to set the default value in datepicker as null and want to be clearable also,
but when the value is null, the date is not show on the datepicker and show error `RangeError: Invalid time value`

here the code:

```
<v-menu
  ref="menu"
  v-model="menuEnd"
  :close-on-content-click="false"
  transition="scale-transition"
  offset-y
  min-width="290px"
>
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
    <v-text-field
      :value="detail.endDate"
      label="End Date"
      prepend-icon="mdi-calendar"
      readonly
      v-on="on"
      color="primary"
      clearable
    ></v-text-field>
  </template>
  <v-date-picker
    v-model="detail.endDate"
    @change="onEndDateChange"
    no-title
    scrollable
    show-current="false"
  ></v-date-picker>
</v-menu>
```

data

```
data() {
  return {
    menuEnd: false,
    detail: {dateEnd: null},
  }
},
methods: {
  onEndDateChange() {
    this.menuEnd = false
  }
}
```

the result is here

[image: result]

Usually I use default value like `moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')`

I still working on this one, and maybe anyone can help me.

## Update

on [Vuetify Doc](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers/#show-sibling-months), the default value is null, and the date is show, but in my case, date is not showing

Comment: Can you try with `undefined` instead of `null`?

Comment: nope, same result here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you bind a "string" value to the `show-current` property instead of a boolean. You forgot the vue binding `:` or `v-bind`.

```html
<v-date-picker
    v-model="detail.endDate"
    @change="onEndDateChange"
    no-title
    scrollable
    :show-current="false" <!-- HERE -->
></v-date-picker>
```

See working codepen: https://codepen.io/Kapcash/pen/LYyNLyg?editors=1011

Comment: Well the solusion in not fully correct but it help, for my solution is remove the show-current and add  :min="detail.startDate" in the <v-date-picker, thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to [Vuetify docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers/#caveats), `v-date-picker` accepts ISO 8601 date string, which have the format you've mentioned ('YYYY-MM-DD'), as you can check on the [ISO 8601 page](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html) as well.

So a `null` value could be indeed the issue here.
Checking on their [API docs for `v-date-picker`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-date-picker/#props-value), the default value is `undefined`, so if you change your `null` by an `undefined` should make the trick.

Another option, one I've used many times when writing this kind of date picking, is to use as default the value for `today`, making it easy for the user to locate himself, and even allowing for going thru the form without picking, when aiming for today.

And this implementation could come from either:

1. using a computed value (I'd recommend that), which would start with `today` if the initial value is null, and then update itself using a [computed setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter).
2. using some default into your data variable

In any case, providing a default value is still what I'd recommend to you.

Comment: already try with undefined as default, but the result is same the calendar not showing any date, and thank you for your recomendation but I need the value to be empty / no value at first

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going for the complex answer, try the simple and just return an empty string "". In my case I'm using a computed property.

```
 <v-date-picker
            v-model="getCreationDate"
 ></v-date-picker>

computed: {
    getCreationDate() {
      return this.editedCourse.creationDate != null
        ? "this.$root.$options.filters.JSdateMDY(this.editedCourse.creationDate"
        : "";
    },
},
```